# A collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable

Tags: general-topology

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that every B $\in$ $\boldsymbol{A}$ is nonmeager and has the Baire Property, and if B, C $\in$ $\boldsymbol{A}$ are distinct, then B $\cap$ C is meager. Show that the collection $\boldsymbol{A}$ is countable.

**NOTES:** If every subset in the collection $\boldsymbol{A}$ is nonmeager, then they cannot be written as the countable union of subsets which are nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, since they have the Baire property, we know that there is an open set U of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for each B, B$\bigtriangleup$U (the symmetric difference) is meager. For the collection $\boldsymbol{A}$ to be countable, we need to show that it's finite or countably infinite, right? I am unsure how to put this all together and show this.

Comment: By "there is an open set $U$ such that for each $B$, $B\triangle U$ is meager" I think you mean "for each $B$, there is an open set $U$ such that $B\triangle U$ is meager". Right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each $B_i \in \mathbf{A}$ can be written $B_i = U_i \triangle M_i$ where $U_i$ is open and nonempty, and $M_i$ is meager.  Now show that $B_i \cap B_j = (U_i \cap U_j) \triangle M_{ij}$ where $M_{ij}$ is an appropriate meager set.  Since $B_i \cap B_j$ is meager, $U_i \cap U_j$ must be empty.  So you have a collection of pairwise disjoint nonempty open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbf{A}$.  Now use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$  is separable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf A=\{B_i:i\in I\}.$

Since $B_i$ has the Baire property, $B_i=U_i\triangle M_i$ where $U_i$ is open and $M_i$ is meager; and $U_i\ne\emptyset,$ since $B_i$ is nonmeager.

If $i\ne j,$ then $U_i\cap Uj\subseteq(B_i\cap B_j)\cup M_i\cup M_j$ is meager, since $B_i\cap B_j$ is meager. Since $U_i\cap U_j$ is open, this means that $U_i\cap U_j=\emptyset.$ Now, since $\{U_i:i\in I\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint nonempty open subsets of $\mathbb R,$ it follows that $I$ is countable.